# How to distribute an iPhone app for testing without getting UDIDs or jailbreaking?

Tags: ios, beta-testing

I have a normal Apple Developer Program (not the **Enterprise** one) 
and I need to distribute an iOS application without adding each UDID to the provisioning profile. I do not want to jailbreak iphones.

1. It is possible to make an Enterprise provisioning profile where the signed applications can be installed on any device without adding it to the provisioning profile. (Correct?)
2. And it is possible only with Enterprise program. (Correct?)
3. Are there any other ways to get rid of this dummy need of adding the betatester's UDIDs and recompiling the app whenever new testers come, with Apple Developer Program only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing you're already registered with the Apple Developer Programme, you can upload your build and from within iTunesConnect use the **TestFlight** options to make your app available for download.

There are two options, '**Internal Testing**' and '**External Testing**'.

(*In answer to question about the profiles, you **don't** need to have an Enterprise Provisioning Profile.*)

As you wish to make the app available for unknown devices, you will need to use *external testing*. Here is a link to Apple's info on it https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

You will need the email addresses of the beta users (up to 1000 users) as those will be used to send an invitation to download via **TestFlight** from the device they wish to download to.

For external testing, your app will need to be submitted to Apple for **Beta Review**, which normally only takes a day or so for them to approve. Once approved this build is available to invite the beta testers to download

I hope this helps

Comment: But how about exporting an IPA package - is it possible to omit Beta Review, put the IPA e.g. to diawi.com with no need of adding UDIDs? (I didn't manage).

Comment: @ZbigniewWiadro I can't comment on diawi.com, as I've never used it, though Apple's new External Testing worked well for me on several occasions. The Beta review never took more than a day for me (unlike the average week of normal review submission) and it allows you do make your app available without the UDIDs